# How can I send the contents of a Word document as plain-text email?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a Word document (saved as a macro-enabled template) that allows a user to fill out a "time off" form using drop-down boxes. It's set up to email the supervisor an attachment with the request; however, the document saves itself when used, which could potentially reveal sensitive information to the next person viewing the form.

Would it be possible to send the document content as plain text in the body of the email (we are using Outlook) so that the document doesn't have to be saved? Or is there a function to add that will allow for the email to send and then the contents to be reset and then re-saved?

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  Dim OL As Object
  Dim EmailItem As Object
  Dim Doc As Document
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Set Doc = ActiveDocument
  Doc.Save
  With EmailItem
    .Subject = "TIME OFF REQUEST"
    .Body = "THE ATTACHED DOCUMENT IS A DAY OFF REQUEST"
    .To = "Email"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send
  End
  With Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set Doc = Nothing
  Set OL = Nothing
  Set EmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821853(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Document class returns a Range object that represents the main document story. The [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195101(v=office.15).aspx) property returns the plain, unformatted text of the range. So, here is the code you are looking for:

```
.Body = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
```

Be aware, Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can use the Word object model for manipulating the message body. You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

Finally, you may find the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.